# Optimizing Quanstrat MACD with apply.paramset returns error

Tags: r, quantmod, quantstrat, domc, blotter

I am trying to test some trading strategies involving digital currency. One such strategy involves MACD crossovers, but I would like to optimize the `nSlow` & `nFast` parameters.

Here's a reproducible example (which runs):

```
library(httr)
library(plyr)
library(quantstrat)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(IKTrading)  # install_github("IlyaKipnis/IKTrading")

poloniex.ohlc.30m <- content(GET("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_ETH&start=1439010600&end=9999999999&period=1800"))  # https://poloniex.com/support/api/
ETHBTC.30m <- ldply(poloniex.ohlc.30m, data.frame)  # Convert OHLCV to data.frame
ETHBTC.30m$date <- as.POSIXct(ETHBTC.30m$date, origin = "1970-01-01")

# Create 'xts' object:
ethbtc.30m.xts <- xts(ETHBTC.30m[, 2:8], order.by = ETHBTC.30m$date)  # is.OHLCV(ETHBTC.30m)

# Rebuild empty environments if RStudio's "Clear All" has been used:
if (!exists('.instrument')) .instrument <- new.env()
if (!exists('.blotter')) .blotter <- new.env()
if (!exists('.strategy')) .strategy <- new.env()

## Optional: Subset timeframe
ETHBTC <- ethbtc.30m.xts[,c("open", "high", "low", "close", "volume")]["2016-02-01::"]

## Define instruments
currency(c('BTC', 'ETH'))  # ls_currencies()
exchange_rate('ETHBTC', currency = 'BTC', counter_currency = 'ETH', tick_size = 0.00001)

initDate = '2016-02-01'
initBTC <- 100
initETH <- 0

portfolio.name <- "crypto"
account.name <- "poloniex"
strategy.name <- "accumulator"
symbols <- "ETHBTC"

## To rerun
rm.strat(portfolio.name)
rm.strat(account.name)
rm.strat(strategy.name)

## Initialize Portfolio, Account, and Orderbook
initPortf(name = portfolio.name, symbols = symbols, initPosQty = 0, initDate = initDate, currency = "BTC")  # getPortfolio(portfolio.name)
initAcct(name = account.name, portfolios = portfolio.name, initDate = initDate, initEq = 0, currency = "BTC")  # getAccount(account.name)
initOrders(portfolio = portfolio.name, symbols = symbols, initDate = initDate)  # getOrderBook(portfolio.name)
strategy(strategy.name, store = TRUE)  # summary(getStrategy(strategy.name))

## Indicators
# Parameters
.nFast = 60 # 90
.nSlow = 130
.nSig = 45 # 75

add.indicator(strategy.name, name = "MACD", arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))), label=NULL)

## Signals
# See Also: applySignals add.indicator link{add.rule} sigComparison sigCrossover sigFormula sigPeak sigThreshold
# MACD
add.signal(strategy.name, "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("macd.MACD.ind", "signal.MACD.ind"), relationship = "gt"),
           label = 'longEntry')
add.signal(strategy.name, "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("signal.MACD.ind", "macd.MACD.ind"), relationship = "gt"),
           label = 'signal.gt.macd')
add.signal(strategy.name, "sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column = "macd.MACD.ind", threshold = 0, relationship = "gte"),
           label = 'macd.gte.threshold')
add.signal(strategy.name, "sigAND",
           arguments=list(columns=c('signal.gt.macd', 'macd.gte.threshold'), cross=FALSE),
           label="longExit")

# Order sizing
osFixedDollar <- function(timestamp, orderqty, portfolio, symbol, ruletype, ...)
{
  ClosePrice <- as.numeric(Cl(mktdata[timestamp,]))
  orderqty <- round(tradeSize/ClosePrice,-2)
  return(orderqty)
}
tradeSize <- initBTC/2

## Rules
# Entry
add.rule(strategy.name,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="longEntry",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty=1000,
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long',
                          osFUN='osFixedDollar'),
         type='enter',
         label='EnterLONG',
         storefun=FALSE)

# Exit
add.rule(strategy.name,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="longExit",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty='all',
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long',
                          osFUN='osFixedDollar'),
         type='exit',
         label='ExitLONG',
         storefun=FALSE)

## Run it
applyStrategy(strategy.name,
              portfolios=portfolio.name,
              parameters=list(nFast = .nFast, nSlow = .nSlow, nSig = .nSig, maType = 'EMA'),
              verbose=TRUE)

updatePortf(Portfolio=portfolio.name,Dates=paste('::',as.Date(Sys.time()),sep=''))
updateAcct(account.name)
updateEndEq(account.name)

## Evaluate
t(tradeStats(portfolio.name))
getTxns(portfolio.name, Symbol = 'ETHBTC')
perTradeStats(portfolio.name, "ETHBTC")

chart.Posn(Portfolio=portfolio.name,Symbol=symbols, type = "line", log.scale = T)
plot(add_Vo())
plot(add_MACD(fast=.nFast, slow=.nSlow, signal=.nSig,maType="EMA"))  # nFast = 60, nSlow = 180, nSig = 40, maType = 'EMA'
```

The above runs perfectly-fine. However, I want to vary the `nFast` and `nSlow` parameters to the `MACD()` function:

```
## Parameter distribution testing
add.distribution(strategy.name,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'nFast',
                 variable = list(nFast = 60:80),
                 label = 'NFAST')

add.distribution(strategy.name,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'nSlow',
                 variable = list(nFast = 180:200),
                 label = 'NSLOW')

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=detectCores())

results <- apply.paramset(strategy.name, paramset.label = "optEMA", portfolio=portfolio.name, account=account.name, nsamples=0)
```

This gives me the following error, which I'm not sure how to debug:

```
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6, ... attempt to select less than one element>
```

What am I doing wrong? FWIW, I am using Ubuntu 12.04/14.04. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please don't [cross post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2016q1/013837.html). Or, at the very minimum, tell people you're cross posting so they don't waste their time answering a question that's already been answered on a forum they don't follow.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Sorry about that. I'll make a note of that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out.

The `component.label` argument in the `add.distribution` function needs to match the `label` argument from `add.indicator`. So in this particular case, I changed my `add.indicator` to:

```
add.indicator(strategy.name, name = "MACD", arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata))), label='MACD')
```

And then changed my `add.distribution` to:

```
add.distribution(strategy.name,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'MACD',
                 variable = list(nFast = 60:80),
                 label = 'NFAST')

add.distribution(strategy.name,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'MACD',
                 variable = list(nSlow = 180:200),
                 label = 'NSLOW')
```

And it runs. Leaving this up here in case anybody else stumbles into a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I am having more or less the same problem with this code

```
################################# MACD PARAMETERS OPTIMIZATION

.fastMA = (30:60)
.slowMA = (50:80)
.nsamples = 10

# Paramset

add.distribution(volStrat,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'macd.out', 
                 variable = list(n = .fastMA),
                 label = 'nFAST'
)

add.distribution(volStrat,
                 paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'macd.out', 
                 variable = list(n = .slowMA),
                 label = 'nSLOW'
)

add.distribution.constraint(volStrat,
                            paramset.label = 'optEMA',
                            distribution.label.1 = 'nFAST',
                            distribution.label.2 = 'nSLOW',
                            operator = '<',
                            label = 'optEMA'
)

results <- apply.paramset(volStrat, 
                          paramset.label = 'optEMA', 
                          portfolio = portfolio2.st, 
                          account = account.st, 
                          nsamples = .nsamples, 
                          verbose = TRUE)

stats <- results$tradeStats

print(stats)
```

The error that comes is:

```
Error in must.be.paramset(strategy, paramset.label) : 
  optEMA : no such paramset in strategy VIXSPY_MACD
```

I really don't understand how to selct the `paramset.label` value.

Thank you so much